Debian 11.9 - /mnt 100% use
So I have a Debian VM running in Azure which is being used as a syslog server.
My logs go to an Azure storage container which is mounted in my VM.
myroot@myvm:/mnt$ df -h
Filesystem                                               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                                     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                    791M  504K  791M   1% /run
/dev/sda1                                                 30G  8.2G   20G  30% /
tmpfs                                                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                    5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sdb1                                                 16G   16G     0 100% /mnt
/dev/sda15                                               124M   11M  114M   9% /boot/efi
//syslogs.file.core.windows.net/file-myvm                5.0T   14G  5.0T   1% /mnt/file-myvm
tmpfs                                                    791M     0  791M   0% /run/user/1000

The /mnt directory is showing that is it 100% full. If I try to find out what this 16G is it points me to the mounted Azure storage which actually has 5T free.
myroot@myvm:/tmp$ sudo du -cha --max-depth=1 /mnt | grep -E "M|G"
9.5G    /mnt/file-myvm
9.5G    /mnt
9.5G    total

So my question is, is it the /dev/sdb1 partition that is full?
How do I fix this?
I do not know where to start as I am confused if this is a storage issue or a partition management issue.
Additional info
I think this is the step where something is not quite right:
I have recreated /mnt2 again and attempted to move over the contents from /mnt
mkdir /mnt2
mount -o bind /mnt /mnt2
cd /mnt2/file-myvm

But there doesn't seem to be anything in the subdirectory /file-myvm to copy over.
myroot@myvm:/mnt$ sudo mount -o bind /mnt /mnt2
myroot@myvm:/mnt$ cd /mnt2
myroot@myvm:/mnt2$ ls
file-myvm
myroot@myvm:/mnt2$ cd file-myvm/
myroot@myvm:/mnt2/file-myvm$ ls
myroot@myvm:/mnt2/file-myvm$ cd /mnt
myroot@myvm:/mnt$ ls
file-myvm
myroot@myvm:/mnt$ cd file-myvm/
myroot@myvm:/mnt/file-myvm$ ls
myroot@myvm:/mnt/file-myvm$

Despite it being empty, it sttll says 16G is being used
/dev/sdb1        16G   16G     0 100% /mnt


please try du -xh /mnt/*/

It had been a while since I looked at this so asked the question again with more up to date info.
The answers can be found here Azure VM (Debian 11.9) root directory 100% full...but its not!

If answers to your other question helped solve this problem, please consider closing this question as a duplicate of the other one.

I would guess the log server has at some point been started before the Azure storage was mounted, and so it has created some files on the local filesystem on sdb1. Before mounting the Azure storage container, /mnt/file-myvm/ would be an empty directory created to act as a mount point.
Now, the log server has been writing to that directory instead of the Azure storage container mounted on top of it. You might have some log data you'll need to transfer from there to the Azure container.
You would have to stop the log server and unmount the Azure container to see the files hidden by the overlapping Azure container. If you would not want to do that (as it would probably mean the loss of some log data), the alternative is to make a bind mount that would allow you to access just the sdb1 filesystem in a different location.
mkdir /mnt2
mount -o bind /mnt /mnt2
cd /mnt2/file-myvm

Now, compare the contents of /mnt/file-myvm (= the Azure container) and /mnt2/file-myvm (just the sdb1 filesystem). Use fuser /mnt2/file-myvm/* to make sure the log server is not still holding the files on sdb1 open: if it is, send a SIGHUP to it, or otherwise make it reread its configuration and close & re-open its log files, just like when performing a scheduled log rotation.
Once fuser confirms nothing is holding the files of /mnt2/file-myvm/* open, find out if they contain anything important. You might want to make a sub-directory on /mnt/file-myvm/ and move them there, as the filenames might otherwise overlap with files already present on the Azure container:
mkdir /mnt/file-myvm/recovered-logs
mv /mnt2/file-myvm/* /mnt/file-myvm/recovered-logs

After that, df -h /mnt should show it no longer 100% full.
The last step would be to undo the bind mount:
cd /
umount /mnt2
rmdir /mnt2 

Usually, the syslog daemon is one of the earliest processes to start at boot time. It normally starts before networking is started, and so before the Azure container can be mounted. You would have to add a load order dependency to rsyslog.service (or whatever you're using as a syslog daemon) to prevent that:
systemctl edit rsyslog.service

then type in:
[Unit]
Wants=mnt-file\x2dmyvm.mount
After=mnt-file\x2dmyvm.mount

and save the file.
You can get the path to use on the Wants= and After= lines with the command:
 systemd-escape --path --suffix=mount /mnt/file-myvm


Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a comprehensive answer! You are about to save my life!
I have managed to copy allof the files over to a recovery directory within /mnt/file-myvm but the original /mnt is still showing as 100% full.
I am happy everything has copied over correctly.
If I still go ahead and unmount it whilst it contains data will it cause any issues?

I actually tried to unmount /mnt and it won't let me as it says it is busy
mylroot@myvm:/$ sudo umount /mnt
umount: /mnt: target is busy

If you copied the files out of /mnt2/file-myvm instead of moving them as I suggested, the originals are still in /mnt2/file-myvm, and you'll now have to delete them as a separate step. You cannot unmount /mnt as long as one of its sub-directories is in use as a mount point for the /mnt/file-myvm filesystem.

I copied and pasted al lof your commands from the previous, I must have gone wrong somewhere. It let me delete /mnt2 so that must have been empty. I shall try again, I'll be right back!

The mount -o bind /mnt /mnt2 makes /mnt2 essentially an alternate way to access the filesystem at /mnt, but without any overlapping filesystems, so you can see the files hidden by the /mnt/file-myvm mountpoint at /mnt2/file-myvm. (If you wanted a bind mount that included any sub-mountpoints for some reason, you would use mount -o rbind instead.)

Added my latest findings to the bottom of my question.

@Beckyboo Almost a duplicate of an earlier answer.

Something might be holding open a deleted file on /mnt. Run sudo lsof +L1 and see if it outputs anything similar to /mnt/<something> (deleted) in the NAME column. Then see COMMAND and PID columns on the same line to find out which process is holding onto a deleted file. If possible, restart that process.
